# Is import and export of a schedule job possible in Mosaic?

Tags: import, export, scheduler, mosaic-decisions

In **Mosaic Scheduler**, I have created a schedule job in one environment `(e.g. DEV)` then can I export the schedule from `DEV` environment and then import it to some another environment just like import/export of flows.

**Does Mosaic provide any such feature for schedule jobs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do have feature like `import/export` in scheduler. Follow below steps to achieve the same.

1. From listing page select the number of schedule jobs that has to be exported.
2. Click on export button. It will export `.zip` file which will include the `json` files of all the selected schedule.
3. On another environment click the import schedule button available on schedule listing page. on which a popup appear where you have to select the import strategy `( override / create with backup)`
4. You can `Drag 'n' Drop` or `click` and select the downloaded `.zip` file.
5. Schedule jobs will imported based on strategy chosen.